# Using grepl to find strings of a certain length

Tags: r, string, grepl

Sample data

```
a<-c("hi","four","seven", "six", "high")
```

how is it possible to select all strings with length equals to 4?

this is my attempt

```
a[grepl(length(a)==4,]
```

Comment: nchar() not length().

Comment: Not efficient, but if you really want to do it with grepl you can use `a[grepl("^.{4}$", a)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want the `nchar` function.  `grep` and its counterparts look for strings within strings, and `length` describes the number of entries in a vector or list

```
> nchar(a)
[1] 2 4 5 3 4
> a[nchar(a)==4]
[1] "four" "high"
```